# Uploading Multiple images on Box from iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, box-api, box, boxapiv2

I am currently working on an iOS application in which i have to upload multiple images on Box,after authentication process. when i select more than 5 images at a time it always upload 5 images and more than 5 images stop uploading. Error messages comes on the log like::

```
[BoxAPIOperation connectionDidFinishLoading:]: BoxAPIOperation <BoxAPIMultipartToJSONOperation: 0xa64eb20> POST https://upload.box.com/api/2.1/files/content did finsh loading

2014-08-25 12:53:36.484 Pbm[13499:4903] -[BoxAPIOperation finish]: BoxAPIOperation <BoxAPIMultipartToJSONOperation: 0xa64eb20> POST https://upload.box.com/api/2.1/files/content finished with state 3

2014-08-25 12:53:36.485 Pbm[13499:4903] -[BoxAPIOperation connection:didFailWithError:]: BoxAPIOperation <BoxAPIMultipartToJSONOperation: 0xa642d00> POST https://upload.box.com/api/2.1/files/content did fail with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1021 "request body stream exhausted" UserInfo=0xa334970 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://upload.box.com/api/2.1/files/content, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://upload.box.com/api/2.1/files/content, NSLocalizedDescription=request body stream exhausted, NSUnderlyingError=0xa32fb70 "request body stream exhausted"}

2014-08-25 12:53:36.485 Pbm[13499:4903] response : (null)

2014-08-25 12:53:36.485 Pbm[13499:4903] error  : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1021 "request body stream exhausted" UserInfo=0xa334970 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://upload.box.com/api/2.1/files/content, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://upload.box.com/api/2.1/files/content, NSLocalizedDescription=request body stream exhausted, NSUnderlyingError=0xa32fb70 "request body stream exhausted"}
```

i am not getting the issue for "request body stream exhausted" . Please help me out if any body had done the uploading process on Box.

Thanks in advance.